# Outer and inner measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I want to prove that $m_{∗}(A \cap (a, b)) = (b − a) − m^*
(A^c \cap (a, b))$.

> Since $(a,b)$ is open, it is measurable. Then $(b-a)=m^*((a,b))=m_*((a,b)$.
>
> Also by the definition of measurable set $m^*((a,b))=m^*(A \cap (a,b))+m^*(A \cap (a,b)^c)$.

But the original problem includes the complement of set $A$ instead of $(a,b)$. What am I doing wrong in this proof?

It seems like if set $A$ is measurable, then we can easily derive this equality.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you need: the definition of inner measure $m_*$.  Without a definition, we can prove nothing about it.

Comment: @GEdgar the definition of inner measure says that it is the least upper bound of measures of closed set contained in the given set. Then I am not sure how it can be used

Comment: OK, use closed subsets $F$ of $A^c \cap (a, b)$ because their complements $(a,b)\setminus F$ are open sets that contain $A \cap (a, b)$.

Comment: @GEdgar why do we choose  $F$  to be a subset of $A^c \cap (a,b)$? I thought it should be $A \cap (a,b)$ since we are interested in its inner measure

Comment: You are right, I switched the two.  Or I switched $A$ and $A^c$.

Comment: @GEdgar then $m_*(A  \cap (a,b))=\sup m(F) = \sup (m(a,b) - m(A^c \cap (a,b)) = (b-a) - inf (A^c \cap (a,b)) = (b-a) - m^*(A^c \cap (a,b))$ . Is it right?